# Grouping with xslt and child nodes

Tags: xslt, grouping

I have tried some of the examples here, but I still can't get the correct output. I haven't worked much with XSLT before. I want to group on the "Detail" element and get all the "Data" elements matching that group as children to the "Detail" element.

Example:

input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<File>
  <Detail type="A" group="1" >
    <Data>
      <Nr>1</Nr>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <Nr>2</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
  <Detail type="B" group="1">
    <Data>
      <Nr>3</Nr>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <Nr>4</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
  <Detail type="B" group="2">
    <Data>
      <Nr>5</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
  <Detail type="A" group="1">
    <Data>
      <Nr>6</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
</File>
```

Wanted output ("Detail type="A" group="1"> elements grouped together and all the  elements matching that group as children)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<File>
  <Detail type="A" group="1" >
    <Data>
      <Nr>1</Nr>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <Nr>2</Nr>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <Nr>6</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
  <Detail type="B" group="1">
    <Data>
      <Nr>3</Nr>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <Nr>4</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
  <Detail type="B" group="2">
    <Data>
      <Nr>5</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
</File>
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: This question languished in the bin for 6 hours before I took it up. My answer languished in the bin for two hours before someone else disguised some non-essential comments as an answer.

---

Study up on Muenchian grouping. It's handy for these grouping problems.

The heavy lifters are `<xsl:key>`, which creates a key based on a concat of @type and @group, and this line here, `<xsl:for-each select="File/Detail[count(. | key('details', concat(@type,'_',@group))[1]) = 1]">`, which isolates the first occurrence of the Detail node having a particular key and by extension a particular pairing of @group and @type.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
     <xsl:key name="details" match="Detail" 
             use="concat(@type,'_',@group)"/>
    <xsl:template match='/'>
      <File>
        <xsl:for-each select="File/Detail[count(. | key('details', concat(@type,'_',@group))[1]) = 1]">
          <xsl:sort select="concat(@type,'_',@group)" />
          <Detail type="{@type}" group="{@group}">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('details', concat(@type,'_',@group))">
              <xsl:copy-of select="Data"/>  
           </xsl:for-each>
          </Detail>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </File>
   </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for help and explanation, and for being the first person that took up my question. Both answers helped me understand how xslt grouping works.

Comment: @user1663498 Glad to help. I understand it better now, too. Thanks for approving my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**I. XSLT 1.0**

Here's a solution that makes use of push-oriented templates, rather than `<xsl:for-each>` (which is normally a more reusable approach).

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:key name="kDetailAttr" match="Detail" use="concat(@type, '+', @group)" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <File>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Detail[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kDetailAttr', concat(@type, '+', @group))[1])]" />
    </File>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Detail">
    <Detail type="{@type}" group="{@group}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('kDetailAttr', concat(@type, '+', @group))/Data" />
    </Detail>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to the original XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File>
  <Detail type="A" group="1">
    <Data>
      <Nr>1</Nr>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <Nr>2</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
  <Detail type="B" group="1">
    <Data>
      <Nr>3</Nr>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <Nr>4</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
  <Detail type="B" group="2">
    <Data>
      <Nr>5</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
  <Detail type="A" group="1">
    <Data>
      <Nr>6</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
</File>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<File>
  <Detail type="A" group="1">
    <Data>
      <Nr>1</Nr>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <Nr>2</Nr>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <Nr>6</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
  <Detail type="B" group="1">
    <Data>
      <Nr>3</Nr>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <Nr>4</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
  <Detail type="B" group="2">
    <Data>
      <Nr>5</Nr>
    </Data>
  </Detail>
</File>
```

**Explanation:**

- By properly applying the [`Muenchian Grouping Method`](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) (which is necessary in XSLT 1.0, given that it does not have any "inline" grouping mechanism), we can find unique nodes and group their descendants.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0**

**When this XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <File>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Detail"
      group-by="concat(@type, '+', @group)">
        <Detail type="{@type}" group="{@group}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/Data" />
        </Detail>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </File>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to the original XML, the same correct result is produced.**

**Explanation:**

- By properly applying XSLT 2.0's [`for-each-group`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group) element, we can arrive at the same result.