# XSLT How to append one child element if another child element is repeating

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML where there are two child elements, I want to append second child elements if the first one is repeating.
Below is the request XML

```
<SelectedOffer>                     
<SelectedOfferItem>
    <OfferItemRefID>SP2F-58379439-103-1_ADT</OfferItemRefID>
    <PaxRefID>PAX1</PaxRefID>   
</SelectedOfferItem>
<SelectedOfferItem>
    <OfferItemRefID>SP2F-58379439-103-1_ADT</OfferItemRefID>
    <PaxRefID>PAX2</PaxRefID>
</SelectedOfferItem>
<SelectedOfferItem>
    <OfferItemRefID>SP2F-58379439-103-1_CHD</OfferItemRefID>
    <PaxRefID>PAX3 </PaxRefID>
</SelectedOfferItem>
<SelectedOfferItem>
    <OfferItemRefID>SP2F-58379439-103-1_CHD</OfferItemRefID>
    <PaxRefID>PAX4</PaxRefID>
</SelectedOfferItem>
<SelectedOfferItem>
    <OfferItemRefID>SP2F-58379439-103-1_INF</OfferItemRefID>
    <PaxRefID>PAX5</PaxRefID>
</SelectedOfferItem>
```

Expected result would be like

```
<OfferItems>
<OfferItem OfferItemID="SP2F-58379439-103-1_ADT">
    <PassengerRefs>PAX1 PAX2</PassengerRefs>
</OfferItem>
<OfferItem OfferItemID="SP2F-58379439-103-1_CHD">
    <PassengerRefs>PAX3 PAX4</PassengerRefs>
</OfferItem>
<OfferItem OfferItemID="SP2F-58379439-103-1_INF">
    <PassengerRefs>PAX5</PassengerRefs>
</OfferItem>
```

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I could see some similar questions now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374327/grouping-with-xslt-and-child-nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 it's as simple as

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="SelectedOfferItem" group-adjacent="OfferItemRefID">
  <OfferItem OfferItemId="{current-grouping-key()}">
    <PassengerRefs>
      <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/PaxRefID"/>
    </PassengerRefs>
  </OfferItem>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this quick approach, it got worked for 2.0!

Comment: Hi Michael, could you please check this query? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67922817/xslt-2-0-group-adjacent-based-on-attribute-value